# What is wrong in require()?

Tags: solidity, remix

The voter can be registered only once but the code below registers more than one voter with same address

```
struct Voter {
       string name;
       uint8 age; 
       bool voted;
       address voterID;
       bool voterRStatus;
    }
    Voter[] public voters;
    
    mapping(address => Voter) voter;
    
    function voterRegistration(string memory _name,uint8 _age) public {
        require(voter[msg.sender].voterRStatus == false);
        voters.push(Voter(_name,_age,false,msg.sender,true));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you include the code you used to add a voter, and how you confirmed that there were in fact two Structs with the same address?

Answer (score 0):

After this:

```
require(voter[msg.sender].voterRStatus == false);
```

Add this:

```
voter[msg.sender].voterRStatus = true;
```

---

As an improvement suggestion, consider changing this:

```
Voter[] public voters;
```

To this:

```
address[] public voters;
```

And this:

```
voters.push(Voter(_name,_age,false,msg.sender,true));
```

To this:

```
voters.push(msg.sender);
```

Since `voter[voters[i]]` gives you all the information that you need.

Comment: May I know why voters.push(Voter(_name,_age,false,msg.sender,true)); did not set voterRStatus

Comment: @NivedhaS: It has set it in the `voters` array, not in the `voter` mapping, which is the one that you are checking inside the `require` statement.